# Update git project from remote repository

Tags: git, fetch, checkout, reset, pull

I have a git project. I would like this to be updateable via a PHP file. That means I always want to have the current status from the remote repository. This doesn't work properly with `git pull` and my local files aren't updated. I would also like that there is a PHP file that undoes all changes `git reset`(?) down to individual files. Is that possible?

Comment: What have you tried so far? And please describe your problems clearly.

Comment: There are also submodules. I've tested it really simple. I deleted a file in the folder. Then i write "git pull" and the file should be restored from the repository. But it wasn't restored. Git fetch and git checkout doenst bring me the files either.

Comment: Did you try `git restore`?

Comment: `git restore --recurse-submodules .` seems to work. And how can i overwrite my files except 1 or more specific?

Comment: If you're scripting this workflow, just save a copy of the file(s) you don't want to restore, do the restore, and then overwrite those files back from the saved copy.